# ORCID iD Inclusion in SpringNature Manuscript Submission

Tags: journals, paper-submission, springer, digital-researcher-id

I am currently preparing a paper for submission to the International Journal of Data Science and Analytics (JDSA) by SpringNature. I have filled out all the required information in the submission forms. I am in the review stage of the form, which is the last step before submission. After this stage, no changes are allowed. However, I have not yet been asked for my ORCID iD, as indicated in the submission guidelines. Even their [source page on ORCID](https://www.springernature.com/gp/researchers/orcid) states: "You can include your ORCID iD in our manuscript submission systems".

**My question is whether the journal will automatically include my ORCID iD after the submission process, or if I need to somehow manually add the ORCID iD to our manuscript?**

Answer (score 2):

The [submission guidelines](https://www.springer.com/journal/41060/submission-guidelines#Instructions%20for%20Authors_Text) for JDSA ask you to include "If available, the 16-digit ORCID of the author(s)" in the author information on the title page. I would interpret this as meaning they want you to manually add the ORCID(s) to the manuscript.

I only have experience with other journals by the same publisher, which automatically pull the ORCID from your "personal profile" in the submission system. Even though JDSA apparently works differently, you may want the ORCID connected to your profile for future submissions and to let the publisher update your ORCID profile when the paper is published. If you haven't yet connected the ORCID, the procedure is probably similar to what's stated [here](https://www.nature.com/nmat/submission-guidelines/orcid):

> 1. Log in using this link - Submit manuscript
> 2. Click ‘Modify My Springer Nature Account’
> 3. Under the ‘Personal Profile’ tab, click ‘Create/link an Open Researcher Contributor ID (ORCID)’